# Set Default page in asp.net 2.0

Tags: asp.net

i have a default.aspx page and many .aspx pages. we navigate to other .aspx page only from default.aspx page.

the requirement is suppose a user has bookmarked any of the other .aspx page, if the other .aspx page existthe user must be forced go to default page. How to achieve this, am using VS2005 and not using any authentication.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if our answers solved your problem then please accept it.........

Answer (score 1):

You can check `Request.UrlReferrer`, if it's not "default.aspx" redirect to default page.

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to go for URL rewriting. For more info please    [Read this](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/) and to implement [Use this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2538/URL-Rewriting-with-ASP-NET)

Comment: This will redirect all requests to Default.aspx, which is not desired behavior. Btw. why you call it AdminBase?